# аналог .rows у тега <ul>

Tags: javascript, html

Есть скрипт который получает таблицу. (Это из битрикса, если что)

```
BasketPoolQuantity.prototype.updateQuantity = function()
{
    var items = BX('basket_items');
    console.log(items);

    if (basketJSParams['USE_ENHANCED_ECOMMERCE'] === 'Y')
    {
        checkAnalytics(this.lastStableQuantities, items);
    }

    if (!!items && items.rows.length > 0)
    {
        for (var i = 1; items.rows.length > i; i++)
        {
            var itemId = items.rows[i].id;
            this.currentQuantity[itemId] = BX('QUANTITY_' + itemId).value;
        }
    }

    this.lastStableQuantities = BX.clone(this.currentQuantity, true);
};
```

`basket_items` это таблица

```
<table id="basket_items"></table>
```

У объекта есть параметр `rows` в котором собираются строки таблицы (`<tr>`)
далее как видно в скрипте эти строки перебираются циклом и в `currentQuntity` записывается значение.

Все ок.

Но мне нужно заменить `<table id="basket_items"></table>` на `<ul id="basket_items"></ul>` в вёрстке и соответственно `tr` на `li`, но у `ul` нету свойства `rows`.

вот что выводит `console.log(items)`

```
ul#basket_items
​
accessKey: ""
​
accessKeyLabel: ""
​
assignedSlot: null
​
attributes: NamedNodeMap [ id="basket_items" ]
​
baseURI: "http://mirraprod.ru/"
​
childElementCount: 38
​
childNodes: NodeList(75) [ #text, div.bx_ordercart_photo_container, #text
, … ]
​
children: HTMLCollection { 0: div.bx_ordercart_photo_container, 1: div.bx_ordercart_itemgroup, 2: h2.bx_ordercart_itemtitle
, … }
​
classList: DOMTokenList []
​
className: ""
​
clientHeight: 722
​
clientLeft: 0
​
clientTop: 0
​
clientWidth: 455
​
compact: false
​
contentEditable: "inherit"
​
contextMenu: null
​
dataset: DOMStringMap(0)
​
dir: ""
​
draggable: false
​
firstChild: #text "
```

Какой аналог `rows` у `ul`?

Как переписать скрипт чтоб заработало со списком?

Comment: `console.log(items);` что показывает? уже у списков, не в таблицы

Comment: @InDevX добавил в ответ

Comment: `rows` => `children`

Comment: @InDevX ага, уже сделал так работает